# fortran : trying to make a minimal stack datastructure

Tags: stack, fortran, fortran90, fortran95, fortran2003

A question about stacks on SO, finally! All my life has led me to this point.

So I needed to incorporate some rather large custom datastructure I made into a stack. I decided to write a minimal stack structure consisting of one integer value only.  Here it is -

```
MODULE STACK_MODULE
 IMPLICIT NONE

 TYPE ELEMENT_TYPE
  INTEGER(4) :: VAL
  TYPE(ELEMENT_TYPE), POINTER :: PREV
 END TYPE ELEMENT_TYPE

 TYPE STACK_TYPE
  INTEGER(4) :: SIZE=0
  TYPE(ELEMENT_TYPE), POINTER :: LASTIN
 END TYPE STACK_TYPE

 CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE PUSH(VAL_,STACK)
   IMPLICIT NONE
   INTEGER(4), INTENT(IN) :: VAL_
   TYPE(STACK_TYPE), INTENT(INOUT) :: STACK
   TYPE(ELEMENT_TYPE),TARGET       :: CURRENT
   ! INIT CURRENT
   CURRENT%VAL = VAL_
   CURRENT%PREV => STACK%LASTIN
   ! ADD CURRENT TO STACK
   STACK%LASTIN => CURRENT
   STACK%SIZE = STACK%SIZE+1
   RETURN
  END SUBROUTINE PUSH

  SUBROUTINE POP(STACK,VAL_)
   IMPLICIT NONE
   TYPE(STACK_TYPE), INTENT(INOUT) :: STACK
   INTEGER(4)      , INTENT(OUT)   :: VAL_
   TYPE(ELEMENT_TYPE), POINTER     :: B4LASTIN
   !WRITE TO VAL_
   IF (ASSOCIATED(STACK%LASTIN)) THEN
    VAL_ = STACK%LASTIN%VAL
    !TAKE OUT THE LAST-IN ELEMENT
    B4LASTIN => STACK%LASTIN%PREV
    STACK%LASTIN => B4LASTIN
    STACK%SIZE = STACK%SIZE-1 
   ELSE
    IF (STACK%SIZE.NE.0) THEN
     PRINT*, STACK%SIZE
     STOP 'MISMATCH BETWEEN STACKSIZE AND POINTER: BAD BOOK KEEPING!'
    END IF
   END IF
   RETURN
  END SUBROUTINE POP 
END MODULE STACK_MODULE

PROGRAM MAIN
 USE STACK_MODULE
 IMPLICIT NONE
 INTEGER(4) :: I,J
 TYPE(STACK_TYPE) :: STACK1
 DO I = 1,10
  CALL PUSH(I,STACK1)
 END DO
 DO WHILE (ASSOCIATED(STACK1%LASTIN))
  CALL POP(STACK1,J)
  PRINT*, J
 END DO
END PROGRAM
```

The result surprised me considerably! I had doubts about whether the `SIZE` counter would keep up .. but not this.

```
          10
 -1076898780
     1752444
 -1219604480
  1651076143
 stderr
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0xB777FD63
#1  0xB77803F0
#2  0xB78713FF
#3  0x8048666 in __stack_module_MOD_pop
#4  0x80487A3 in MAIN__ at prog.f95:?
```

Any pointers (*pauses while giggling uncontrollably*) on where I went wrong?
[Here is the link to the code on IDEONE.](http://ideone.com/xMJ2mW)
EDIT: [The IDEONE link](http://ideone.com/xMJ2mW) now contains the updated version of the code, with the solution incorporated into it! Hope it can be reused as a generic template for stacks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few minor problems

1) When PUSH exits, CURRENT disappears with it.  You need something like

```
TYPE(ELEMENT_TYPE),POINTER       :: CURRENT
! INIT CURRENT
ALLOCATE(CURRENT)
```

2) Likewise when POP finishes, it needs to delete the data so

```
B4LASTIN => STACK%LASTIN%PREV
DEALLOCATE(STACK%LASTIN)
STACK%LASTIN => B4LASTIN
```

3) ASSOCIATED works but only if the pointers are initialized properly.

```
TYPE(STACK_TYPE) :: STACK1
STACK1%LASTIN => NULL()
```

And you should be ready to run.

Comment: your suggested edit #1 seems to do the trick. Why is it important to have the other two ?

i have changed the code on the IDEONE site already - you might have a look!

Comment: #2 so you don't get a memory leak, #3 so that associated fails when you get to the end of the list.

Comment: wow! +1.  
do you think the `=>null()` associated in #3 can be done during the declaration?\\
    `TYPE STACK_TYPE`  
      `INTEGER(4) :: SIZE=0`
      `TYPE(ELEMENT_TYPE), POINTER :: LASTIN=>NULL()`
    `END TYPE STACK_TYPE`
\\
the compiler does not seem to give any errors .. but i do not know if pointer association can be done during declaration.

Comment: Yes it can be done during initialization.  In fact, that is actually neater, especially if you have several of them.